# Microsoft Azure AD On Behalf of Flow with B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to implement an "On Behalf Of" flow using Java and ADAL4J. The application is registered in the B2C tenant, and requires access to graph api via our own facade to graph.

The steps I have so far are:-

1) Authentication - successful and redirects me to the application page.
2) Upon redirection I call to Azure with the client code to obtain the token(s).
3) The next step attempts to exchange tokens to that I can use the new token to call graph.

Steps 2 fails as it only returns an ID Token, the Access Token and Refresh Token are not supplied.

Am I attempting to do something that is not supported as I've been through most of the documentation and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Some of the documentation from last year actually suggests that this flow is not supported - I'd like to confirm hence me asking the question here....

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Azure AD B2C does not currently support "on behalf of" flows. You can vote for the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18431254-b2c-support-for-on-behalf-of-flow) to help the B2C team prioritize it.

Access tokens will be available in the next few weeks! Stay tuned to the [Azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/topics/identity-access-management/).

Comment: The link for voting seems to point to "B2C Support for client credential flow" instead of the on-behalf-of flow.