# Azure AD B2C with ASP.NET Web API issue token for both authentication in Web API and accessing MS Graph API

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm new to ASP.NET and Azure AD B2C in general. My goal is to create ASP.NET 5 application which will be accessible through react-frontend with MSAL library. On frontend I have successfully issued both access and id tokens to authorize in my application without any problem, and they are accepted by ASP.NET backend and authorize user requests. I've encountered problem as soon as I tried to access user in current context of request on Back-end. This token does not simply allow me to call MS Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` with token that I get, to get data about user. The error I get is

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Invalid x5t claim.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-11-29T15:48:41",
            "request-id": "91b63eeb-0346-4ab2-9d31-ca58e8d1e30b",
            "client-request-id": "91b63eeb-0346-4ab2-9d31-ca58e8d1e30b"
         }
    }
}
```

After additional research I found out that tokens that are used for authentication for Back-End are not usable for retrieval of user data from AD B2C or Graph API, since currently [AD B2C does not support "on-behalf-of" flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787317/microsoft-azure-ad-on-behalf-of-flow-with-b2c#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20B2C%20does%20not%20currently%20support%20%22on,few%20weeks%21%20Stay%20tuned%20to%20the%20Azure%20blog.).

How can I implement authentication flow where I still use AD B2C as authentication provider and user data provider for my application ? Additionally, in future, I want enable users to store their own secrets in Azure Key Vault, which can be done only, as far as I understood, via Graph API.

Comment: Why call /me when all data is returned in the token? The only solution is to use AAD Client_Credential flow to have your web server to call MS Graph directly, using a token it obtains itself. You cannot use the users AAD B2C token to call /me endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure your app and API using the B2C tokens, then have the API itself generate its own token to access Graph API. The MS Docs have instructions for how to set your app up to [get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

In your case your app would take the user's ID from the user-specific access token it was passed, then use it's own access token to make a call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<useridfromtoken>` to [get the user's details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

If the information you need is stored in the B2C directory but not returned in the token, and you don't want to give your app access to the entire directory via Graph, then another option is to implement a [userinfo endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

If you want users to store secrets in Key Vault (assuming this is some function of your API) then you need to be looking at the [.NET Key Vault secret client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net).